# Numpty Physics: fullscreen? additional levels in a .deb?

Tags: games

I recently discovered Numpty Physics, possibly the best game ever in the history of the world... or close to that :) http://numptyphysics.garage.maemo.org/

Anyway, I have two questions:

1. Can I put the game in fullscreen?
2. I have noticed that the Windows port has other levels, possibly more than the Ubuntu package in the repositories. Any idea how I can get more levels in a .deb or a repository? I am thinking about deploying it eventually in a school, and it would be better to have nice packages.

Answer (score 1):

1. I couldn't figure a way to change the screen size in the provided amd64 binary (the svn version has a useful-looking `-geometry` option, though)
2. Are the Windows extra levels by any chance from the [NP-complete collection](http://numptyphysics.garage.maemo.org/levels/)? If so, the quick and (really) dirty way is to just copy them over to /usr/share/numptyphysics -- a nicer way would be to get the svn source and make a new .deb package, but unless you're developing for maemo, it does not seem to build out-of-the-box.

(In case someone else wants to try the provided .deb on amd64, there seems to be a bug which makes it crash on start: it assumes the data files are in `.` so you can work around that by doing `cd /usr/share/numptyphysics` first.)